# Каким шрифтом пишут от руки (в противоположность типографскому письму)?

Tags: правописание

Читаю [курсив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) и не понимаю, это то самое или нет?
[Русское курсивное письмо](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE) противопоставляется "русскому рукописному письму". Каким же письмом я всю жизнь писал? Может прописью? Но пропись для заглавных букв вроде.

Английский вроде однозначнее, там если handwriting значит [cursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive). Но в статье нет ссылки на русскую википедию, что подтверждает моё мнение, что в русском языке нет чёткого слова, обозначающего данное понятие. Чему учат детей в первом классе на уроках "Письма"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писать от руки можно либо рукописным письмом (производной от скорописи), либо печатными буквами (имитирующими книжное написание).
"Русское курсивное письмо" не противопоставляется "русскому рукописному письму", как минимум, в Wiki это одна и та же страница.

В английском существует точно такое же разделение и handwriting вовсе не значит cursive. (Для уточнения разницы погуглите обсуждения школьных реформ в духе "Should we still use cursive handwriting?"). При этом handwriting может использоваться в качестве синонима к слову cursive, как и написано в Wiki. То же самое в русском: можно сказать "рукописный почерк / рукописная запись", подразумевая "курсив".

В типографике русское понятие "рукописный/каллиграфический" соответствует английскому handwriting/script.

Детей учат писать печатными буквами в детском садике и рукописным письмом в первом классе.

Comment: Ок, а пропись и курсив это одно и то же?

Comment: Пропись может употребляться в качестве синонима к рукописному письму ("Записать число прописью" в значении словами, а не цифрами), а значит, к курсиву. При этом: а) "пропись" имеет другие значения, напр., и тетрадь, в которой занимаются дети, и собственно образцы рукописных букв - это все прописи; б) рукописный текст - это не обязательно курсив, могут быть и т.н. "печатные буквы".

Comment: Не понял почему курсив, приведёный в качестве примера в детской тетради нужно называть прописью, а не курсивом и какое отношение писмо печатными буквами имеет к прописи?

Comment: Примеры в детских тетрадях называются прописями, потому что представляют собой _прописанные_ буквы. Такие тетради, собственно, и называются "тетради _с прописями_", разговорное именование "прописи" применительно к самим тетрадям возникло позднее. Ваш вопрос был "пропись - это курсив?" Ответ: нет, не только. Печатные буквы в комментарии выше упомянуты как один из видов рукописного письма, в дополнение к курсиву. Например, в финансовых и почтовых документах иногда встречаются требования "записать сумму прописью печатными буквами".

Answer (score 3):

Тут смотрите какая штука, нужно чётко определиться с терминологией.

**Шрифт** В самом широком смысле - графическое начертание букв. Чаще всего, когда мы говорим о шрифтах, мы имеем ввиду типографские шрифты, хотя и это словосочетание стремительно устаревает - нынешние компьютерные шрифты всё-таки - не набор типографских литер.

**Рукописное письмо** В самом широком смысле - любая практика написания текстов не машинным способом. В чуть более узком смысле - некоторая устоявшаяся культурная традиция начертания букв носителями данного конкретного языка. То есть это некоторая общепринятая форма начертания, а, значит, мы можем говорить о том, что это шрифт, хотя исторически так вышло, что шрифтом это называть не принято.

**Курсив** Вид начертания типографских шрифтов, возникший под влиянием, собственно, рукописных форм письма. Его основная характеристика (но не единственная! - см. [абзац](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) про наклонный шрифт) - наклон.

**Русское курсивное письмо** - наиболее распространённая форма русского рукописного письма **и** его типографского аналога (впрочем, на практике применяемого крайне редко).